# iOS; Is It Possible To Set An Animated Icon As A UITabController Icon?

Tags: ios, animation, icons, uitabbar

I'm trying to figure out a nice way to add a "busy" animation to my app.

Since it's such a modeless app, I don't want the animation to be too obtrusive, but I think that animations in the top bar are way too easy to miss.

I'd like to set an animation in the UTIabBar of my app, indicating that the viewcontroller for that tab is busy.

I spend a lot of time generating animations (I use Adobe Illustrator or 3D modelers, and that can be a big task).

UITabController does some funky effects to icons, and I'm wondering if it would puke on an animated UIView.

Has anyone done this? Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a UITabBar, this is not practically possible, and would result in a pretty nauseous UI experience anyhow.

It *might* work better if you used subtly animated controls as part of a more general flamboyant UI - but tread carefully - aim for clarity above flashiness.

Comment: Good answer. I'll figure something out.